# Mapping of time based models to database

Tags: database-design, orm

Currently I'm developing a movie reservation system for diving into Spring Framework.

I'm using Spring Data JPA for database modeling. I have several model classes but I am stuck with time-based logic in my application and can't finish modelling phase.

Here's the general design of my classes.

> every `CinemaHall` has one or more `Showrooms`
>
> every `Showroom` has different number of `Seat`s and `Session`s
>
> every `Session` is assigned to a `Movie`.

My problem is, I can't decide how a reservation should be done. A reservation of course must be made for a specific `Seat` instance. That `Seat` instance in fact belongs to a `Showroom`. But the reservation information of `Seat` can vary for different `Session`s.

In order to solve this problem, I can declare a `seats` field in `Sessions`, but then lots and lots of `Seat` instance will be created for all `Session`s of that `Showroom`(all these instances are eventually persisted to database)

The second problem is every `Session` has a datetime field, naturally, so that a user can choose from the day and hour of available `Sessions`. But since datetime is a temporal notion, it can go forever. What i mean is, I can't decide if I should pre-create a week, a month or a year's all `Session`s in the database, or do the creation whenever a user demands a reservation from that `Session`.

If I choose pre-creating, say a week of `Session`s, than when a week passes, should I recreate new ones or is doing it as a scheduled database procedure called every night a more convenient way?

Comment: This sounds more like a question about how cinemas do their scheduling rather than a software engineering problem, so the best person to answer would be someone who runs a cinema.    I would expect they have some standard business rules they use to figure out their timetable before putting any tickets on sale.    The other alternative if you don't know those business rules would be to provide a mechanism which allows the cinema owner to be able to input the schedule into the system themselves.

Comment: Thanks for you comment. I'll further search for the logic.

Comment: To answer the other question. What you are missing is an entity called a ticket (or any other suitable name) which links chair, session and possibly the customer it was sold to, and for how much. These are created as part of a booking when several tickets (and other goods/services) may be sold.

Comment: thank you. I'll implement this right away.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You wrote

> A reservation of course must be made for a specific Seat instance. [...] But the reservation information of Seat can vary for different Sessions.

That sounds pretty straightforward: create a class `Reservation` which holds a reference to a `Seat` (or multiple seats, if that's more convenient), the related `Session` and (as Kain0_0 mentioned in a comment) the `Customer` who made the reservation.

Of course, there is space for some error here: a `Reservation` could reference a `Seat` which belongs to a `Showroom` which does not match the `Session`, but I would not try to solve this through the database model, this is something the application should care for not to happen.

> The second problem is every Session has a datetime field [...], bt since datetime is a temporal notion, it can go forever

A `Session` does not only need a starting time, but also a length (in hours/minutes), so you can determine its end. The `Movie` has a length, too, which should fit into the session (the latter should usually allow some extra time for letting the guests in and out, showing advertisements, clean-up after the show etc).

If `Movie.Length <= Session.Length` holds is again something the application should check, not your database model.

> I can't decide if I should pre-create a week, a month or a year's all Sessions in the database, or do the creation whenever a user demands a reservation from that Session.

I think it is not sensible to assume the `Session` instances as something which might be precreated by the program automatically, or "whenever a user demands a reservation".

In real life, there will be a person (probably an operator from the cinema) who has to define the sessions some days or weeks ahead of time, and to enter the information which movie shall be shown in which showroom at what time - that is  a **manual planning** activity, nothing your program can do automatically. Placing of reservations will only be possible after the planning has happened. And it should not be your program's concern how many days ahead the operators do the planning, it should be in their own interest to do this right in time.

Of course, the application should care for making it impossible to create overlapping sessions for the same showroom. But this another point where I would recommend against prevention by the database model.

Comment: that is a very precise and detailed answer. helped me a lot.